# Python GroupBy time interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to ask your help to perform an operation over a pandas dataframe.

My initial dataframe is the following:

[image]

and I would like to reshape it in interval of 30Second and compute the mean for each group.

I used the following:

```
 df_a['avgValue']= df_a['value'].groupby([df_a['id_A'],df_a['course'], pd.TimeGrouper(freq='30S')]).transform(np.mean)
```

and I get the following:

[image]

BUT the ts_A is not grouped by 30 second. For instance, the first and second rows should be merged in one, obtaining the expected result:

```
id_A               ts_A course weight avgValue
id1 2017-04-27 01:35:30 cotton 3.5    150.000
id1 2017-04-27 01:36:00 cotton 3.5    416.000
...
```

My question is: How should I change the above code to obtain the expected result?

Many Thanks in advance.
Best Regards, 
Carlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need (assuming `ts_A` is set to `DatetimeIndex`) [`GroupBy.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) and omit `transform` function:

```
#if not datetimeindex
#df['ts_A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts_A'])
#df = df.set_index('ts_A')


df = df_a['value'].groupby([df_a['id_A'],
                            df_a['course'], 
                            df_a['weight'],
                            pd.TimeGrouper(freq='30S')]).mean().reset_index()
```

Or:

```
df = df_a.groupby(['id_A','course','weight', 
                   pd.TimeGrouper(freq='30S')])['value'].mean().reset_index()
print (df)
  id_A       course  weight                ts_A       value
0  id1       cotton     3.5 2017-04-27 01:35:30  150.000000
1  id1       cotton     3.5 2017-04-27 01:36:00  416.666667
2  id1       cotton     3.5 2017-04-27 01:36:30  700.000000
3  id1       cotton     3.5 2017-04-27 01:37:00  950.000000
4  id2  cotton blue     5.0 2017-04-27 02:35:30  150.000000
5  id2  cotton blue     5.0 2017-04-27 02:36:00  450.000000
6  id2  cotton blue     5.0 2017-04-27 02:36:30  520.666667
7  id2  cotton blue     5.0 2017-04-27 02:37:00  610.000000
```

Solution with `resample`:

```
df = df_a.groupby(['id_A','course','weight'])['value'].resample('30S').mean().reset_index()
print (df)
  id_A       course  weight                ts_A       value
0  id1       cotton     3.5 2017-04-27 01:35:30  150.000000
1  id1       cotton     3.5 2017-04-27 01:36:00  416.666667
2  id1       cotton     3.5 2017-04-27 01:36:30  700.000000
3  id1       cotton     3.5 2017-04-27 01:37:00  950.000000
4  id2  cotton blue     5.0 2017-04-27 02:35:30  150.000000
5  id2  cotton blue     5.0 2017-04-27 02:36:00  450.000000
6  id2  cotton blue     5.0 2017-04-27 02:36:30  520.666667
7  id2  cotton blue     5.0 2017-04-27 02:37:00  610.000000
```

SETUP:

```
d = {'weight': {0: 3.5, 1: 3.5, 2: 3.5, 3: 3.5, 4: 3.5, 5: 3.5, 6: 3.5, 7: 3.5, 8: 3.5, 9: 3.5, 10: 5.0, 11: 5.0, 12: 5.0, 13: 5.0, 14: 5.0, 15: 5.0, 16: 5.0, 17: 5.0, 18: 5.0, 19: 5.0}, 'value': {0: 100, 1: 200, 2: 350, 3: 400, 4: 500, 5: 600, 6: 700, 7: 800, 8: 900, 9: 1000, 10: 100, 11: 200, 12: 450, 13: 300, 14: 600, 15: 500, 16: 522, 17: 540, 18: 320, 19: 900}, 'ts_A': {0: '2017-04-27 01:35:40', 1: '2017-04-27 01:35:50', 2: '2017-04-27 01:36:00', 3: '2017-04-27 01:36:10', 4: '2017-04-27 01:36:20', 5: '2017-04-27 01:36:30', 6: '2017-04-27 01:36:40', 7: '2017-04-27 01:36:50', 8: '2017-04-27 01:37:00', 9: '2017-04-27 01:37:10', 10: '2017-04-27 02:35:40', 11: '2017-04-27 02:35:50', 12: '2017-04-27 02:36:00', 13: '2017-04-27 02:36:10', 14: '2017-04-27 02:36:20', 15: '2017-04-27 02:36:30', 16: '2017-04-27 02:36:40', 17: '2017-04-27 02:36:50', 18: '2017-04-27 02:37:00', 19: '2017-04-27 02:37:10'}, 'course': {0: 'cotton', 1: 'cotton', 2: 'cotton', 3: 'cotton', 4: 'cotton', 5: 'cotton', 6: 'cotton', 7: 'cotton', 8: 'cotton', 9: 'cotton', 10: 'cotton blue', 11: 'cotton blue', 12: 'cotton blue', 13: 'cotton blue', 14: 'cotton blue', 15: 'cotton blue', 16: 'cotton blue', 17: 'cotton blue', 18: 'cotton blue', 19: 'cotton blue'}, 'id_A': {0: 'id1', 1: 'id1', 2: 'id1', 3: 'id1', 4: 'id1', 5: 'id1', 6: 'id1', 7: 'id1', 8: 'id1', 9: 'id1', 10: 'id2', 11: 'id2', 12: 'id2', 13: 'id2', 14: 'id2', 15: 'id2', 16: 'id2', 17: 'id2', 18: 'id2', 19: 'id2'}}
```

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame(d)
df_a['ts_A'] = pd.to_datetime(df_a['ts_A'])
df_a = df_a.set_index('ts_A')
print (df_a)
                          course id_A  value  weight
ts_A                                                
2017-04-27 01:35:40       cotton  id1    100     3.5
2017-04-27 01:35:50       cotton  id1    200     3.5
2017-04-27 01:36:00       cotton  id1    350     3.5
2017-04-27 01:36:10       cotton  id1    400     3.5
2017-04-27 01:36:20       cotton  id1    500     3.5
2017-04-27 01:36:30       cotton  id1    600     3.5
2017-04-27 01:36:40       cotton  id1    700     3.5
2017-04-27 01:36:50       cotton  id1    800     3.5
2017-04-27 01:37:00       cotton  id1    900     3.5
2017-04-27 01:37:10       cotton  id1   1000     3.5
2017-04-27 02:35:40  cotton blue  id2    100     5.0
2017-04-27 02:35:50  cotton blue  id2    200     5.0
2017-04-27 02:36:00  cotton blue  id2    450     5.0
2017-04-27 02:36:10  cotton blue  id2    300     5.0
2017-04-27 02:36:20  cotton blue  id2    600     5.0
2017-04-27 02:36:30  cotton blue  id2    500     5.0
2017-04-27 02:36:40  cotton blue  id2    522     5.0
2017-04-27 02:36:50  cotton blue  id2    540     5.0
2017-04-27 02:37:00  cotton blue  id2    320     5.0
2017-04-27 02:37:10  cotton blue  id2    900     5.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. However, how can I give a name to the new created column that contains the avg?

Comment: I am working on sample, but it is not easy use your data because pictures.

Comment: I see. Many Thanks in advance for it.

Comment: I used this one but it did not solve the problem either: df = df_a['value'].groupby([df_a['id_A'],
                            df_a['course'], 
                            df_a['weight'],
                            pd.TimeGrouper(freq='30S')]).transform(np.mean)

Comment: Yes? Some problem?

Comment: the problem is not solved yet. I need to get what showed above as the expected result.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you miss I omit `transform`, only I use `mean`. Can you check it?

Comment: It seems that df.resample should help here, but not sure how to use it with the above code.

Comment: bad output :                                                                                                      ts_A
2017-04-27 01:35:40    150.000000
2017-04-27 01:35:50    150.000000
2017-04-27 01:36:00    416.666667
2017-04-27 01:36:10    416.666667
2017-04-27 01:36:20    416.666667
2017-04-27 01:36:30    700.000000
2017-04-27 01:36:40    700.000000
2017-04-27 01:36:50    700.000000
2017-04-27 01:37:00    950.000000

Comment: Can you check my setup data?

Comment: what you mean? where is it?

Comment: I can send you my csv files if it is more appropriate

Comment: I add to my answer to end sample data. also resample solution was added, but same output.

Comment: THANKS YOU JEZRAEL. yes with resample and .reset_index() the problem has been solved.

Comment: Supeeeeer, I am really happy ;) Please accept solution - click on the check mark (`✓`). Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149733/discussion-between-carlo-allocca-and-jezrael).

Comment: I am using the solution which use resample and is taking ages...20-30 minutes on a datasets of few mega. Is there a way to improve it?

Comment: If really big dataframe it is problem. Only some RAM helps :(. But some improvent should by if all values are sorted like `df = df.sort_values(['id_A','course','weight'])` and then use `df_a.groupby(['id_A','course','weight'], sort=False)['value'].resample('30S').mean().reset_index()`

Comment: uhhhh...the df is about 500M. How do I add more RAM?

Comment: Hmmm, obviusly need some server with more RAM or another PC - it is hardware problem... But if run your code in your code in your laptop, it is problematic because very large df :(

Comment: does it mean that I should change approach when the dataset get up to Giga? pyspark?

Comment: Yes, pyspark or dask can handle big data. In my opinion if working with 500MB csv need 4GB RAM, better 8GB. Is possible to test it?

Comment: Many Thanks Jezrael. I tried it with 8GB and the execution is much much faster, very few seconds. However, I am going to try DASK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149994/discussion-between-carlo-allocca-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should set the datetime column as index, as `TimeGrouper` operates on the index.

```
df = df_a.set_index('ts_A')
```

then compute the adjusted groupby operation. Better to groupby the columns you interested in first, and then compute the mean on the target variable.

```
results = df.groupby(['id_A','course','weight', pd.TimeGrouper(freq='30S')])['value'].mean()
```